# Prevent from dropping a database trigger in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a winform Application that I have to install on client machine (with database included in the client machine) and I don't know that someone who knows or has some knowledge in sql/TransSql to delete stuff from database especially triggers because i am using them in that same database to prevent "user who knows Sql" from changing stuff in the database ...
Is there a way or a possibility to make triggers dropping impossible even for the server owner (in this case server on client machine)?

Comment: Short answer: no. That would be, well, terrible, because a poorly written trigger would allow you to hose the entire installation. Even if you wrote the world's worst login trigger that blocks anyone from logging in, this can still be fixed by starting the server in single-user mode and removing it. Similarly, if the machine's administrator hasn't been made a database administrator, there are ways to circumvent that and re-establish access, although there is no way you'd do it accidentally -- so that might be your best option. Administrators, by design, can't be locked out completely.

Comment: No. If they own the server, they can anything they want to it. You enforce object meddling contractually, not technically.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: As in, in the contract you supply to them when they purchase said product, @AnassHadeg , it states that the end user doesn't mess with the data, and if they do, any such actions are at their own risk and are unsupported.

Comment: Aha So at least if the users put  their hands on the data i won't  be responsible for any damage that's seems more logical and less time consuming !

Comment: Every piece of software I've ever purchased has come with some kind of terms of service or similar agreement. Nobody ever reads them (except the lawyers sometimes) but if you put in there that if they "change stuff" then you will either not support them or have the right to charge them to fix it, it won't prevent them from doing it, but it gives you an out if you don't want to get punished for it.

Comment: This works better with one-time purchases or perpetual licenses than with subscription software or ongoing maintenance packages, because there is always the risk that they'll do this thing, come to you for help, you'll point to the contract they agreed to but violated, and they'll terminate their subscription. So you may want to consider making the wording in the contract so that it's flexible enough that if the customer is Microsoft, you can agree to help them make it work (in order to keep the good contract), but if it's me, you can just tell me to pound sand and let me walk away.

Comment: Yes I will make it as one of the first 3 statements in the contract and i 'll state it verbally before every installation it's not surprising how a lot of people never take time reading contracts terms due to the fact that they are "boring and useless" .